# I want to make a duplicate object into each independent object

Tags: materials, objects

[image]

I have a circle of replicated objects, but I want to have each independent object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the object and <kbd>tab</kbd> into *Edit Mode*. Select the entire mesh with <kbd>A</kbd> and then click <kbd>RMB</kbd> and select *Seperate > By Loose Parts*. This should make them all individual objects.